# How many different rooted unlabelled binary trees have exacly 9 nodes and are left-heavy?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I know how many trees are possible using nth Catalan number but don't know how to find left-heavy trees. Is there any technique?

Comment: @user3386109 is the answer 2333?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: 2357

I provide here a reasoned approach (no programming involved) and code to produce the same result, but via a more brute-force method.

## A. Reasoning

Intuitively, it seems easier to count by exclusion. So that leads to this approach:

- Count all the binary trees with 9 nodes. As you already indicated, this corresponds to the 9<sup>th</sup> Catalan number. This is [C<sub>9</sub> = 4862](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).
- Subtract the number of trees whose roots are balanced, i.e. where the two subtrees of the root have equal heights (let's call those subtrees *L* and *R*). That gives us the number of trees that are either left- or right-heavy.
- As there are just as many left- as right-heavy trees, divide this result by two to get the final result.

So now we can focus on calculating the number mentioned in the second bullet point:

### Counting trees that are strictly balanced at the root

A tree of height 2 would have at most 7 nodes (when it is full), so the height needs to be at least 3. A tree of height 5 (that is balanced at the root) needs at least 5 nodes in *A* (on a single path), ***and*** 5 in *B* (also on a single path), so the height cannot be more than 4. We thus have only two possibilities: the height of a 9-node binary tree, that is balanced in the root, is either 3 or 4.

Let's deal with these two cases separately:

### 1. When the height of the tree is 3

In this case we have a tree with 4 levels. Let's analyse each level:

There are 3 nodes in the first two levels: the root and its two children.

The third level is the first level where there can be some variation: that level has between 2 and 4 nodes. Let's deal with those three cases one by one:

#### 1.a Third level has 2 nodes

Here the third level has one node in *L* and one in *R*. Each can either be a left or right child of its parent. So there are two possibilities at either side: 2x2 = 4 possibilities.

There is no variation possible in the fourth level: the four remaining nodes are children of the two nodes in the third level.

Possibilities: 4

#### 1.b Third level has 3 nodes

There are 4 ways to select three positions from the four available positions in the third level. Either *L* or *R* gets only one node. Let's call this node *x*.

In the fourth level we need to distribute the three remaining nodes, such that *L* and *R* get at least one of those. This is achieved when *x* gets either one or two children.

- When *x* gets two children, the other remaining node has 4 possible positions. Here you see those 4 positions in light grey:
  [image]
- When *x* gets *one* child, it can be either a left or right child, and the other *two* remaining nodes can occupy the four available positions (see image above) in 6 ways: 2x6=12.

So given a choice in the third level, there are 4+12=16 possible configurations for the fourth level.

Combining this with the possibilities in the third level, we get 4x16:

Possibilities: 64

#### 1.c Third level has 4 nodes

The third level is thus full. The two remaining nodes on the fourth level need to be split between *L* and *R*, and so each has 4 possible positions. This gives 4x4 = 16 possibilities in total.

Possibilities: 16

### 2. When the height of the tree is 4

When the height is 4, then by consequence *L* and *R* each have only one leaf: they are *chains* of 4 nodes each. This is the only way to make the root strictly balanced ***and*** get a height of 4.

There is no choice for the root node of *L* (it is the left child of the root), but from there on, each next descendant in *L* can be either a left or right child of its parent. The shape of *L* has thus 2<sup>3</sup> possibilities = 8. Considering the same for *R*, we have a total of 8x8 = 64 shapes.

Possibilities: 64

### Total

Taking all of the above together, we have 4+64+16 + 64 = 148 possible shapes that give a tree with a balanced root.

So applying the approach set out at the top, the total number of left-heavy binary trees with 9 unlabelled nodes is (4862-148)/2 = 2357

## B. Code

To make this a programming challenge, here is an implementation in JavaScript that defines the following functions:

- `countTreesUpToHeight(n, height)`: count all binary trees with *n* nodes, that are ***not higher*** than the given height. Uses recursion.
- `countTreesWithHeight(n, height)`: count all binary trees with *n* nodes, that have ***exactly*** the given height. Uses the preceding function.
- `countLeftHeavy(n)`: the main function. Uses the other two functions to count all combinations where the root's left subtree is higher than the right one.

So this approach is not like the *exclusion* approach above. It actually counts the combinations of interest. The output is the same.

```js
function countTreesUpToHeight(n, height) {
    if (n > 2**(height+1) - 1) return 0; // too many nodes to fit within height
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count += countTreesUpToHeight(i, height-1) 
               * countTreesUpToHeight(n-1-i, height-1);
    }
    return count;
}

function countTreesWithHeight(n, height) {
    return countTreesUpToHeight(n, height) - countTreesUpToHeight(n, height-1);
}

function countLeftHeavy(n) {
    let count = 0;
    // make choices for the height of the left subtree
    for (let height = 0; height < n; height++) {
        // make choices for the number of nodes in the left subtree
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // multiply the number of combinations for the left subtree 
            //   with those for the right subtree 
            count += countTreesWithHeight(i, height-1)
                   * countTreesUpToHeight(n-1-i, height-2);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

let result = countLeftHeavy(9);
console.log(result);               // 2357
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the solution. It helped me a lot to improve my thinking in this type of question. If you don't mind, can you explain 1.b with an example? I am a little bit confused on that part.

Comment: I inserted an image with an example for 1.b

Comment: thank for sharing. I was just wondering that with @user3386109  's technique I get 2333 as the answer, that method seems correct. But don't know which answer/method is correct.

Comment: @Romil The difference between my comment and this answer was due to a difference in the definition of "left-heavy". A google search for "left-heavy" supports trincot's definition, and that's why I deleted my comment.